# Descarga de archivos con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Tengo una aplicación hecha con laravel, la misma que tiene como objetivo buscar y descargar archivos en formato mp3.
La aplicacion esta desplegada en un servidor local, y consume los datos de una base de datos alojada en otra máquina. La tabla garabaciones tiene dos campos: nombre_archivo, ruta_archivo, los cuales son devueltos en un archivo json.

El problema esta en que estas grabaciones estan en la misma maquina donde esta la aplicación de laravel pero en fuera de la carpeta de la misma. ¿Puede sugerirme como podría hacer que desde Laravel yo pueda hacer la descarga de estos archivos.

Ya intente poner un enlace:

```
<a href=`${row.ruta_archivo}/4{row.nombre_archivo}` download>
```

Esto nbo funciona debido a que este enlace intenta llevarme a una ubicacion dentro de la misma aplicacion.
Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta creando un enlance simbólico haciendo lo siguiente en la terminal:

1. Posiciónate en la carpeta de donde se dará acceso a la carpeta externa, ejemplo:

`cd proyecto_laravel/public`.

2. Ejecuta el siguiente comando para crear el enlace simbólico:

`ln -s /ruta/completa/de/tuCarpetaExterna nombreDeTuArchivoEnlace`

De esta forma, en una etiqueta `anchor` puedes hacer lo siguiente (si tu enlace simbólico se encuentra en la carpeta `public`):

```
<a href="{{ asset('nombreDeTuArchivoEnlace/archivo.mp3') }}">Descarga Ahora</a>
```

Si necesitas forzar la descarga del archivo, en el método de tu controlador pondrías lo siguiente:

```
return response()->download(public_path('nombreDeTuArchivoEnlace/archivo.mp3'));
```

Y claro, lo mandarías a llamar con alguna ruta que tengas registrada:

```
<a href="{{ route('descarga') }}">Descargar Ahora</a>
```